# Cannot traverse folder using wait group

Tags: go, goroutine

I have this simple script to attempt to traverse the file system and read files line-by-line to match lines on a regex:

```
package main

import (
  "bufio"
  "fmt"
  "io/ioutil"
  "log"
  "os"
  "regexp"
  "sync"
)

type FileWithLine struct{
  Line int
  Path string
}

var set = map[string]FileWithLine{}
var rgx = regexp.MustCompile("ErrId\\s*:\\s*\"[[:alnum:]]+\"");


func traverseDir(d string, wg *sync.WaitGroup){

  fmt.Println("traversing dir:", d)

  if d == ".git"{
    return
  }

  wg.Add(1)
  go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup){

    defer wg.Done()

    files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(d)

    if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for _, f := range files {

      fmt.Println("we see file:", f.Name())

      if f.IsDir() {
       traverseDir(f.Name(), wg)
       return
      }

      file, err := os.Open(f.Name())

      if err != nil {
       log.Fatalf("failed opening file: %s", err)
      }

      scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
      scanner.Split(bufio.ScanLines)


      for scanner.Scan() {
      var line = scanner.Text()

      if rgx.MatchString(line) {
        fmt.Println("line matches:", line);
      }

      }

      file.Close()


    }

  }(wg)


}

func main()  {
  var wg sync.WaitGroup
  traverseDir(".", &wg)
  fmt.Println("Main: Waiting for workers to finish")
  wg.Wait()
  fmt.Println("Main: Completed")
}
```

the problem is that it's exiting before it reads all the files, I get this output:

```
traversing dir: .
Main: Waiting for workers to finish
we see file: .git
traversing dir: .git
Main: Completed
```

but there are more files in the current directory, than just the .git folder. It just so happens that the .git folder is the first item in the current working dir and it exits right after that. Anyone know why my program is exciting early?

Comment: You could also use [`filepath.Walk`](https://godoc.org/path/filepath#Walk) instead of implementing the logic yourself; you can skip the current directory (e.g. `.git`) by returning [`filepath.SkipDir`](https://godoc.org/path/filepath#SkipDir) from the [`filepath.WalkFunc`](https://godoc.org/path/filepath#WalkFunc) you pass to it. If concurrent reads are needed, you can start some worker goroutines and pass the paths to them through a channel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is stopping processing because of these lines:

```
if f.IsDir() {
   traverseDir(f.Name(), wg)
   return
}
```

When it sees a directory, it goes in it and immediately returns, without processing the remaining files in the current directory. And when the first seen directory is ".git", since you handle it as an exception, the nested `traverseDir` also returns.

Comment: yeah I need to use continue instead of return, classic dumb mistake, thx

Comment: it also appears that I don't need to pass the wg pointer around, just use one wg ref at the top of the file?

Comment: Global wg works, but there's nothing wrong passing it around. Most do pass it around.

Comment: Thanks, any idea why global wg works? what's the explanation? I guess memory can be shared automatically across goroutines?

Comment: Msmory is shared but that is not the reason. Global wg is safe to use because wg.Add can be called safely from multiple goroutines.

Comment: ahh I see, so then why are channels necessary to communicate between goroutines? is that because it is memory safe to use channels?